Testing Vue Component with @nuxtjs/i18n: Fixing the "Need to install with app.use function" Error
I'm using the @nuxtjs/i18n library in my Nuxt project, and I'm trying to write a test for a Vue component. However, I keep encountering the error:
Need to install with app.use function
Here’s the basic test I’m working on:
test('renders all child components', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(AppSettings, {
        global: {
            components: mockComponents,
            mocks: {
                $t: (key: string) => key // Mocking the i18n `$t` function
            },
        }
    })

    Object.keys(mockComponents).forEach((componentName) => {
        expect(wrapper.findComponent({ name: componentName }).exists()).toBe(true)
    })
})


Has anyone faced a similar issue or has any ideas on how to fix it?
I've tried multiple solutions to mock the @nuxtjs/i18n integration, but none seem to work. For example, here’s one of the approaches I tried:

import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'

vi.mock('@nuxtjs/i18n', () => ({
    useI18n: vi.fn(() => ({
      t: (tKey: string) => tKey
    }))
}))

config.global.mocks = {
    $t: (tKey: string) => tKey
}


Please, quote the whole error, including call stack. It's not obvious that it refers nuxtjs/i18n in the first place. And provide the component too

My component is fairly simple, and the errors I mentioned are the only ones I encountered (No additional details). I posted the solution that resolved my issue as an answer.

The issue stemmed from i18n not being registered within the tests. I resolved this by creating a setup file with the following configuration:
const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    messages: {
        en //imported path to .json with translations
    }
});

config.global.plugins = [i18n];

This setup file was registered in the vitest.config setupFiles, and everything worked as expected.
